Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::handle(array $record): bool must be compatible
I am upgrading symfony 4.4 to 5.4 using PHP 8.2 after run composer update command then i am facing this issue.
ERROR: Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::handle(array $record): bool must be compatible with Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::handle(Monolog\LogRecord $record): bool

PHP 8.0 & Symfony 4.4 composer.json file that is fine but I must have to upgrade PHP as well symfony version.
Upgraded Composer.json for PHP 8.2 & Symfony 5.4:
Result of composer update -W
ERROR: Compile Error: Declaration of Model\Base\Account::isPrimaryKeyNull() must be compatible with Propel\Runtime\ActiveRecord\ActiveRecordInterface::isPrimaryKeyNull(): bool


That means that 2 packages are not compatible between them. Looks like it is symfony/monolog-bundle and monolog that another package is requiring

Either use Symfony bridge Monolog or use Monolog

Why is this tagged with Laravel? You haven't shared any such code

Please don't use -dev versions, unless you definitely know you need them

I have update all -dev version and downgraded them, as well checked composer.lock file and their suggested versions but nothing happened. I think this is very complicated to find route cause.

Please share which versions you are currently using, as requested in the comment below

Composer.json versions : -- PHP 8.2, symfony 5.4, doctrine/persistence 3.0.0, symfony/monolog-bridge 5.4, symfony/monolog-bundle 3.10.0, propel/propel 2.0.0-beta2. When i used this versions and run composer update command then i am getting different error: Compile Error: Declaration of Model\Base\Account::isPrimaryKeyNull() must be compatible with Propel\Runtime\ActiveRecord\ActiveRecordInterface::isPrimaryKeyNull(): bool. Please suggest.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section - also, please share the exact versions you're currently using, not a repetition of the requirements from composer.json

Hi, This is complete more descriptive details for understand the route cause. please suggest me if possible to outcome in this problem. Thanks

Hi It is solved to explorer more as you advised. Thanks your help and support. Nico Haase.

Neither in Monolog v1 nor in Monolog v2, Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::handle has the given signature. This is part of Monolog v3, but symfony/monolog-bridge in v5.4 is not compatible with that package.
Please check how you installed the MonologBridge. Requiring 3.x-dev of the MonologBundle is not a good idea after all, as this does not target a tagged (and thus stable) version

I have tried with symfony/monolog-bridge but did not work as expected. I also tried to downgrade MonologBundle but not worked as well.

Please add all clarification that helps to understand what you've tried to your question by editing it

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Did you also check whether the packages were installed in the proper versions?

sure i m doing my best .

Then please add all clarification to your question. Share which versions of symfony/monolog-bridge and monolog/monolog you currently installed

Hey Nico Haase please let me know how i can check whether packages were installed in the proper versions? I have updated description what it was and what i did .

Check composer.lock for this
